# How to archive large folder (2.4 gb) to multiple separated independent zip-archives

Tags: linux, ssh, zip

There is a folder with images with the size of 2.4 Gb.

The task is to archive via SSH this folder to multiple separated independent zip-archives.

I have tried:

```
zip -r -s 512m archive.zip folder
```

This command creates dependent zip-archives:

```
archive.z01
archive.z02
archive.z03
archive.z04
archive.zip
```

But I need to create exactly independent zip-archives for "online web service" which optimizes images. This service requires zip archive and size up to 2Gb.

Could you please suggest a working solution?

OS: Linux

Access via: SSH

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short script in bash that will do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`ls *.jpg`

ZIP_PREFIX='archive'
INDEX='1'

MAX_SIZE='512'

for PICT_FILE in $FILES
do
    ZIP_NAME=${ZIP_PREFIX}"_"${INDEX}".zip"
    ARCH_SIZE=`du -m $ZIP_NAME | cut -f 1`


    if [  $ARCH_SIZE -ge $MAX_SIZE  ]; then
            INDEX=`echo "$INDEX + 1" | bc`
    fi

    ZIP_NAME=${ZIP_PREFIX}"_"${INDEX}".zip"

    zip $ZIP_NAME $PICT_FILE

done
```

MAX_SIZE is set in Mb
You can replace command in 'FILES' with `find` or anything else that will provide you with the list of files

Answer (score 1):

the.Legend, thanks for the script.

Here is few notices:

```
1. `du -m $ZIP_NAME | cut -f 1`
```

Returns 1 for files with the size less then 1 Mb.

```
2. INDEX=`echo "$INDEX + 1" | bc
```

Does not work in bash in linux.

Here is updated script which was tested in linux:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=`find ./image/`

ZIP_PREFIX='example.com.image'
INDEX='1'

MAX_SIZE='512000' # 512 Mb

for PICT_FILE in $FILES
do
    ZIP_NAME=${ZIP_PREFIX}"_"${INDEX}".zip"
    ARCH_SIZE=`du -k $ZIP_NAME | cut -f 1`

    # echo $ARCH_SIZE
    # echo $MAX_SIZE

    if [  $ARCH_SIZE -ge $MAX_SIZE  ]; then
            INDEX=$((INDEX + 1))
    fi

    ZIP_NAME=${ZIP_PREFIX}"_"${INDEX}".zip"

    zip $ZIP_NAME $PICT_FILE

done
```

The result is:

```
http://example.com/example.com.image_1.zip [500Mb]  
http://example.com/example.com.image_2.zip [500Mb]  
http://example.com/example.com.image_3.zip [500Mb]  
http://example.com/example.com.image_4.zip [227Mb]
```